# The procedure entry point could not be located in dynamic link library

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5

I have the following error when open my application.

[image]

I'm use `windows 7 32bit` platform, and `Qt v5.3.1` with `MinGW 4.8.2 - 32bit` compiler .
All dll's files with `Qt5Core.dll` for `5.3.1` version already exists .
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You should make sure the application includes the dlls it was linked against. Who created that app? And the dlls?

Comment: `Who created that app` -> me, `And the dlls` -> I have moved the important dll files in order to be beside the executive file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably you get this error because you use dlls from QtCreator directory which was not compiled with `mingw` (often QtCreator compiled with Microsoft visual studio on Windows)

You should use dlls from `C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin` (for example) .

App which was compiled with `mingw` needs dll which compiled with `mingw` too.