# Procedure entry point could not be located after upgrading qt

Tags: windows, qt, dll, linker

My app used to run on windows 7, Qt 5.3.2.
Recently (a month ago) I installed Qt 5.4.1. I installed it using mingw32-make to compile it (version of mingw : 4.9.1). I kept the precedent version.
Just so you know, this computer is a production one. I don't develop my app on it.

A week ago, I wanted to test a new version of my app, still with qt 5.3.2. this message appear when I want to open a window (using a QFileDialog) :

> The procedure entry point ?absoluteDir@QFileInfo@@QEBA?AVQDir@@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt5Core.dll

[Here is the kind of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524620/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-dynamic-link-library) I found on the web.

This didn't work. I use the dll from the right repository.

I checked the paths, I tried to rename the v5.4.1.

I found earlier this week that:

- If I open my app with Qt Creator, (try all these versions : v3.2.1, v3.3.1, v3.4.0), the error doesn't appear.
- If I open NotePad, if I do a "open a new file", the same message appears.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are obviously using the wrong version on Qt's libraries. Try copying the correct ones into your app's directory.

Comment: Hey, I tried to copy all the versions of the qt's libraries, none of them work. And I know when it is not the ones that I compile with cause the app is not working (with the other the QMainWindow is opening). I tried to copy my app in the Qt directory but I have the same issue. I even tried to delete the version of Qt 5.4.1 but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Copy needed Qt 5.3.2 libraries to folder with executable.